# Use Docker --net=host and connect to other containers by hostname

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to setup an Nginx reverse proxy, which works fine, but if I set `network_mode: "host"` it stops working because it is unable to find the hostname of other docker containers. I have a `web` container and an `nginx` container.

I get the following error:
`reverseproxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:80" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10`

My Nginx conf file is:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-web {
        server web:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-web;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
  }
```

and my docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build: .\app
    volumes:
      - .\app:/code
    restart: always
  reverseproxy:
    image: reverseproxy
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - web
```

I need to set network_mode to host else the the `X-Forwarded-For` will wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using a Linux host instead of Windows which meant I didn't need to use network_mode: "host". I also had to change my Python code to

```
request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
```

from

```
request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: Hi, is the answer complete there? I'm trying to log client ip too and I'm not having good time here.

Comment: Dude. Holy crap. I have been pulling my hair out trying to get the IP address and was also looking for host networking solutions. You saved me life with this !